# new label in itemize/minipage/fbox not right

Tags: itemize, minipage, fbox

**What can I do to fix this?  This code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{\rule{.3in}{.1pt}}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3in}
\begin{itemize}
\item This looks good
\item That looks good
\item Oh no, a dim line
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

*makes this:*

[image: How can I make this right.]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what you see is artifact of pgf viewer. try to print result and then compare lines.  lines are very thin ...

Comment: Wow! You are right.  Thank you for knowing and sharing that.  Absolutely astounding.